# Analizar dos listas en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, opencv, ocr

Hola y muchísimas gracias de antemanos por su ayuda!.

Les pongo en contexto. Estoy analizando una imagen con OCR y obtengo todo el texto de esta junto a sus coordenadas (X e Y medida en pixeles). El problema es que cuando analizo el texto, hay texto que está de un circulo que, en la primera linea tiene unas siglas y en la linea que le sigue un código. Necesito que éste código, el que está DENTRO DEL CIRCULO, quede en una sola linea y por consiguiente en un solo item de mi list.

La list que obtengo con el OCR es algo como esto:

```py
[
['2', 747, 34]
['3', 1179, 34]
['5', 2043, 34]
['1', 321, 34]
['6', 2476, 34]
['7', 2907, 33]
['10', 4198, 36]
['63-0110-WM-101-HDPE-6', 3501, 168]
['01', 4121, 180]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 4174, 181]
['63-0110-WM-102-HDPE-6', 3502, 233]
['02', 4120, 244]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 4174, 245]
['A', 2, 278]
['A', 4446, 277]
['63-0110-WM-103-HDPE-6', 3502, 296]
['03', 4120, 308]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 4174, 310]
['63-0110-WM-111-HDPE-6', 3502, 360]
['04', 4120, 373]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 4174, 374]
['63-0110-WM-112-HDPE-6', 3502, 424]
['05', 4120, 433]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 4174, 433]
['63-0110-WM-113-HDPE-6', 3502, 490]
['06', 4120, 504]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 4174, 505]
['63-0110-WM-121-HDPE-6', 3502, 574]
['07', 4120, 584]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 4174, 586]
['63-0110-WM-122-HDPE-6', 3497, 642]
['08', 4120, 648]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 4174, 650]
['63-0110-WM-123-HDPE-6', 3496, 707]
['\xd0\x92', 10, 713]
['09', 4120, 713]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 4174, 715]
['PARTIR/PARAR', 4201, 970]
['HDPE-6', 1405, 978]
['HDPE-6', 1755, 981]
['HDPE-6', 3279, 978]
['HDPE-6', 231, 979]
['HDPE-6', 580, 981]
['HDPE-6', 2113, 978]
['HDPE-6', 2588, 979]
['HDPE-6', 940, 981]
['HDPE-', 2938, 977]
['REMOTO', 4202, 986]
['HS', 4160, 983]
['SS-1', 2136, 1020]
['SS-1', 3309, 1019]
['SS-1', 263, 1019]
['SS-1', 613, 1019]
['SS-1', 963, 1019]
['SS-1', 2961, 1019]
['SS-1', 1437, 1019]
['SS-1', 1787, 1019]
['SS-1', 2611, 1019]
['PLC', 4063, 1079]
['ESTATUS', 4201, 1092]
['FUNCIONANDO', 4201, 1112]
['O', 4088, 1114]
['O', 4116, 1115]
['C', 4, 1150]
['ALARMA', 4201, 1153]
['FALLA', 4201, 1171]
['R\xc3\x89LE', 4267, 1170]
['UA', 4160, 1167]
['ESTATUS', 4202, 1215]
['YL', 4155, 1234]
['LOCAL/REMOTO', 4208, 1235]
['A/B', 4150, 1258]
['ALARMA', 4207, 1276]
['YA', 4156, 1297]
['P/E', 4208, 1296]
['R.C.1', 704, 1235]
['1/2"x2', 764, 1236]
['R.C.1', 354, 1236]
['1/2"x"', 420, 1234]
['R.C.1', 1054, 1236]
['1/2"x', 1109, 1237]
['R.C.1', 2703, 1235]
['1/2"x%"', 2767, 1234]
['R.C.1', 1529, 1236]
['1/2"x2"', 1593, 1235]
['R.C.1', 1879, 1237]
['1/2"x\xc2\xbd', 1934, 1237]
['R.C.1', 2228, 1237]
['1/2"x', 2288, 1237]
['R.C.1', 3052, 1236]
['1/2"x2"', 3117, 1234]
['R.C.1', 3401, 1236]
['1/2"x"', 3467, 1234]
['1/2"-BA-103', 1162, 1333]
['1/2"-\xd0\x92\xd0\x90-113', 2336, 1333]
['1/2"-BA-121', 2811, 1333]
['1/2"-BA-101', 463, 1333]
['1/2"-\xd0\x92\xd0\x90-102', 813, 1333]
['1/2"-BA-11', 1628, 1333]
['1/2"-\xd0\x92\xd0\x90-112', 1978, 1333]
['1/2"-BA-122', 3152, 1333]
['1/2"-BA-123', 3500, 1333]
['PARTIR', 4208, 1355]
['HS', 4160, 1370]
['DPA', 4055, 1360]
['E', 372, 1413]
['E', 721, 1412]
['E', 1546, 1412]
['E', 2245, 1412]
['PARAR', 4207, 1416]
['HS', 4160, 1432]
['SELECTOR', 4208, 1478]
['LR', 4162, 1492]
['LOCAL/REMOTO', 4202, 1499]
['TIPICO', 3751, 1531]
['CONTROL', 3895, 1534]
['P.', 4208, 1538]
['EMERGENCIA', 4236, 1539]
['\xd0\x92\xd0\x9eMBA', 3830, 1552]
['DE', 3903, 1553]
['POZO', 3937, 1552]
['PE', 4161, 1554]
['SUMERGIBLE', 3853, 1576]
['LAH', 2752, 1688]
['YS/D:', 2797, 1694]
['0521/PPV-0121', 2745, 1711]
['LAH', 401, 1684]
['S/D:', 449, 1691]
['0501', 400, 1711]
['PPV-0101', 452, 1714]
['LAH', 753, 1687]
['S/D:', 800, 1693]
['0502', 749, 1713]
['PPV-0102', 801, 1715]
['LAH', 2274, 1688]
['S/D:', 2323, 1694]
['0513/PPV-0113', 2268, 1711]
['LAH', 3448, 1689]
['S/D:', 3490, 1694]
['0523/PPV-0123', 3441, 1711]
['LAH', 1928, 1689]
['S/D:', 1973, 1694]
['0512', 1923, 1711]
['PPV-0112', 1975, 1714]
['LAH', 3099, 1689]
['S/D:', 3144, 1694]
['0522PPV-0122', 3091, 1711]
['LAH', 1100, 1688]
['S/D:', 1146, 1693]
['0503/PPV-0103', 1094, 1711]
['LAH', 1577, 1688]
['S/D:', 1622, 1692]
['0511PPV-01', 1572, 1711]
['11', 1701, 1715]
['LAL', 1098, 1746]
['VLALL', 1142, 1748]
['0503', 1090, 1773]
['0503/', 1134, 1773]
['LALL', 1987, 1747]
['0512', 1924, 1773]
['0512', 1961, 1773]
['LALL', 811, 1749]
['LAL', 1573, 1747]
['LALL', 1635, 1748]
['LALL', 2808, 1747]
['0521', 2750, 1774]
['0521/', 2789, 1774]
['LALL', 3157, 1746]
['LAL', 3457, 1747]
['LALL', 3504, 1747]
['0523', 3441, 1773]
['0523/', 3482, 1773]
['LALL', 462, 1747]
['LAL', 2283, 1747]
['LALL', 2333, 1747]
['05130513/', 2269, 1773]
['LAL', 412, 1746]
['LAL', 762, 1747]
['LAL', 1936, 1746]
['LAL', 2760, 1746]
['LAL', 3107, 1746]
['0502', 747, 1774]
['0502', 787, 1774]
['0511', 1577, 1773]
['0511', 1635, 1773]
['0522', 3093, 1774]
['0522/', 3132, 1774]
['0501A0501/', 399, 1774]
['(NOTA', 587, 1833]
['1', 646, 1835]
['(NOTA', 2593, 1833]
['1', 2652, 1835]
['(NOTA', 227, 1841]
['1)', 293, 1839]
['(NOTA', 937, 1838]
['1)', 1004, 1833]
['(NOTA', 1761, 1833]
['1)', 1827, 1833]
['(NOTA', 3285, 1833]
['1)', 3351, 1833]
['(NOTA', 1411, 1833]
['1)', 1477, 1833]
['(NOTA', 2111, 1838]
['1)', 2177, 1834]
['(NOTA', 2935, 1837]
['1)', 3001, 1833]
['LQI', 962, 1864]
['0503', 957, 1890]
['LQI', 1786, 1863]
['LVM40', 1119, 1868]
['LQI', 2609, 1865]
['0521', 2605, 1891]
['LVM40', 425, 1866]
['LQI', 622, 1865]
['0502', 606, 1890]
['ILVM40', 1596, 1867]
['LVM40', 1943, 1868]
['LVM40', 2292, 1867]
['LVM40', 2767, 1867]
['ILVM40', 3118, 1867]
['LQI', 3320, 1866]
['0523', 3303, 1890]
['LVM40', 3464, 1867]
['LQI', 273, 1865]
['0501', 258, 1889]
['LVM40', 780, 1868]
['LQI', 1447, 1865]
['0511', 1436, 1889]
['LQI', 2147, 1865]
['0513', 2129, 1889]
['LQI', 2971, 1865]
['0522', 2953, 1889]
['0512', 1778, 1891]
['LT', 277, 1986]
['0501', 267, 2007]
['LT', 626, 1987]
['0502', 615, 2007]
['LT', 976, 1987]
['0503', 964, 2007]
['LT', 1451, 1986]
['0511', 1440, 2007]
['LT', 1800, 1987]
['0512', 1789, 2008]
['LT', 2150, 1986]
['0513', 2138, 2007]
['LT', 2624, 1987]
['0521', 2614, 2007]
['LT', 2974, 1986]
['0522', 2963, 2007]
['LT', 3324, 1986]
['0523', 3312, 2007]
['LSHL', 400, 2005]
['0501', 406, 2025]
['LSHL', 751, 2005]
['0502', 756, 2024]
['LSHL', 1099, 2005]
['0503', 1103, 2025]
['LSHL', 1575, 2005]
['0511', 1581, 2025]
['LSHL', 1922, 2006]
['0512', 1922, 2027]
['LSHL', 2271, 2005]
['0513', 2270, 2028]
['LSHL', 2746, 2005]
['0521', 2755, 2025]
['LSHL', 3095, 2005]
['0522', 3094, 2027]
['LSHL', 3443, 2007]
['0523', 3445, 2028]
['E', 5, 2024]
['E', 4446, 2022]
['NOMENCLATURA:', 3760, 2142]
['RP', 2976, 2166]
['INSTRUMENTACI\xc3\x93N', 3873, 2188]
['CON', 4062, 2187]
['EQUIPO', 4111, 2189]
['MAYOR', 4189, 2187]
[':', 3874, 2256]
['RELE', 3891, 2254]
['DE', 3946, 2254]
['PROTECCI\xc3\x93N', 3981, 2254]
['EN', 4103, 2254]
['TABLERO', 4136, 2254]
['DE', 3887, 2276]
['FUERZA', 3921, 2276]
['RP', 3805, 2256]
[':', 3872, 2309]
['RELE', 3891, 2306]
['CONTROL', 3946, 2306]
['DE', 4039, 2306]
['NIVEL', 4074, 2306]
['POZOS', 4131, 2309]
['LVM40', 3789, 2309]
['\xd0\xa2\xd0\x95', 961, 2312]
['0503', 950, 2333]
['\xd0\xa2E', 1436, 2312]
['0511', 1427, 2333]
['TE', 1780, 2312]
['0512', 1768, 2333]
['TE', 2135, 2312]
['0513', 2118, 2335]
['\xd0\xa2\xd0\x95', 2961, 2311]
['TE', 3311, 2312]
['0523', 3294, 2336]
['\xd0\xa2\xd0\x95', 262, 2312]
['0501', 253, 2332]
['TE', 606, 2312]
['0502', 595, 2333]
['TE', 2614, 2311]
['0521', 2605, 2333]
['0522', 2942, 2336]
[':', 3875, 2361]
['CONTROL', 3890, 2359]
['EN', 3983, 2359]
['PANEL', 4019, 2359]
['DE', 4086, 2359]
['FUERZA', 4120, 2359]
['Y', 4211, 2359]
['CONTROL', 3893, 2385]
['DPA', 3798, 2361]
[':', 3876, 2420]
['CORRESPONDE', 3890, 2417]
['A', 4032, 2416]
['PANEL', 4056, 2417]
['L\xc3\x93GICO', 4123, 2417]
['DE', 4198, 2416]
['CONTROL', 3892, 2442]
['PLC', 3800, 2418]
['F', 4447, 2459]
['0110-PBF-0121', 2636, 2469]
['0110-PPV-0121', 2636, 2490]
['0110-PPV-0121A', 2629, 2512]
['0110-PBF-0103', 986, 2469]
['01', 986, 2490]
['10-PPV-0103', 1011, 2490]
['0110-PPV-0103A', 980, 2512]
['0110-PBF-0113', 2160, 2469]
['0110-PPV-0113', 2160, 2490]
['0110-PPV-0113A', 2154, 2512]
['0110-PBF-0101', 285, 2468]
['0110-PBF-0102', 634, 2468]
['0110-PPV-0102', 634, 2490]
['0110-PPV-0102A', 628, 2512]
['0110-PBF-0111', 1459, 2468]
['0110-PPV-0111', 1459, 2490]
['0110-PPV-0111A', 1451, 2512]
['0110-PBF-0112', 1808, 2468]
['0110-PPV-0112', 1808, 2491]
['0110-PPV-0112A', 1802, 2512]
['0110-PBF-0122', 2979, 2468]
['0110-PPV-0122', 2979, 2490]
['0110-PPV-0122A', 2974, 2513]
['0110-PBF-0123', 3327, 2468]
['0110-PPV-0123', 3327, 2490]
['0110-PPV-0123A', 3321, 2512]
['0110-PPV-0101', 285, 2491]
['0110-PPV-0101A', 277, 2512]
['ARCADIS', 3744, 2579]
['Design&Consultancy', 4121, 2547]
['for', 4121, 2563]
['natural', 4148, 2561]
['and', 4201, 2561]
['built', 4121, 2580]
['assets', 4159, 2580]
['0110-PBF-0101@0103', 167, 2658]
['0110-PPV-0101@0103', 653, 2658]
['BOMBAS', 708, 2683]
['VERTICALES', 789, 2683]
['MULTIETAPA', 901, 2677]
['Q:', 665, 2711]
['(m3/h)', 701, 2718]
['TDH:', 655, 2741]
['(m.c.a.)', 726, 2740]
['POT:', 662, 2762]
['2', 727, 2760]
['HP', 749, 2760]
['0110-PBF-0111@0113', 1160, 2658]
['0110-PPV-0111@0113', 1628, 2658]
['BOMBAS', 1684, 2684]
['VERTICALES', 1764, 2683]
['MULTIETAPA', 1875, 2678]
['Q:', 1640, 2711]
['(m3/h)', 1675, 2716]
['TDH:(m.c.a.)', 1639, 2743]
['\xd0\xa0O\xd0\xa2:', 1643, 2762]
['2', 1702, 2760]
['HP', 1725, 2760]
['0110-PBF-0121@0123', 2137, 2657]
['0110-PPV-0121@0123', 2624, 2658]
['CONTRACTOR', 3598, 2651]
['DWG.', 3710, 2651]
['NUMBER', 3759, 2651]
['REV.', 4345, 2655]
['POZOS', 182, 2677]
['DE', 250, 2677]
['SISTEMA', 282, 2677]
['PRIMARIO', 361, 2677]
['DE', 450, 2677]
['CAPTURA', 482, 2677]
['POZOS', 1220, 2677]
['DE', 1288, 2677]
['ZANJA', 1320, 2677]
['CORTAFUGAS', 1382, 2677]
['QUEBRADA', 1272, 2698]
['BLANCA', 1371, 2697]
['BOMBAS', 2686, 2677]
['VERTICALES', 2764, 2677]
['MULTIETAPA', 2872, 2677]
['POZOS', 2169, 2677]
['DE', 2237, 2677]
['MONITOREO', 2270, 2677]
['Y', 2374, 2677]
['CONTINGENCIA', 2397, 2677]
['4768-0110-11-PID-0101', 3773, 2689]
['C', 4379, 2690]
['Q:', 2637, 2711]
['(m3/h)', 2669, 2720]
['TDH', 2626, 2741]
['(m.c.a.)', 2697, 2740]
['\xd0\xa0O\xd0\xa2', 2639, 2762]
['2', 2699, 2761]
['\xd0\x9d\xd0\xa0', 2721, 2760]
['Teck', 3917, 2767]
['(NOTA', 2781, 2765]
['2', 2840, 2767]
['(NOTA', 809, 2765]
['2)', 873, 2765]
['(NOTA', 1784, 2765]
['2)', 1848, 2765]
['COMPA\xc3\x91IA', 3654, 2807]
['MINERA', 3814, 2807]
['TECK', 3933, 2807]
['QUEBRADA', 4024, 2809]
['BLANCA', 4192, 2808]
['S.A.', 4317, 2807]
['QUEBRADA', 3727, 2841]
['BLANCA', 3895, 2839]
['PHASE', 4021, 2839]
['2', 4131, 2839]
['PROYECT', 4169, 2839]
['1.', 2222, 2875]
['SENSOR', 2252, 2875]
['HIDROST\xc3\x81TICO', 2337, 2876]
['SER\xc3\x81', 2502, 2876]
['SUMINISTRADO', 2556, 2875]
['E', 2711, 2875]
['INSTALADO', 2736, 2875]
['POR', 2852, 2875]
['EL', 2906, 2875]
['DATE', 3518, 2875]
['NAME', 3270, 2875]
['SIG.', 3413, 2876]
['G', 1, 2899]
['G', 4446, 2895]
['CONTRATISTA', 2233, 2901]
['DE', 2372, 2901]
['LOS', 2411, 2901]
['POZOS.', 2462, 2901]
['TITLE', 3613, 2921]
['2.', 2220, 2928]
['PENDIENTE', 2253, 2929]
['POR', 2372, 2928]
['INFORMACION', 2426, 2928]
['CERTIFICADA.', 2569, 2929]
['SISTEMA', 3757, 2950]
['CORTAFUGAS', 3868, 2950]
['QUEBRADA', 4034, 2951]
['BLANCA', 4174, 2950]
['INGENIERIA/IMPULSI\xc3\x93N', 3815, 2985]
['DE', 4098, 2979]
['AGUA', 4142, 2979]
['DRAWN:', 3177, 2980]
['M.', 3255, 2980]
['QUEZADA.', 3283, 2981]
['20.06.17', 3517, 2980]
['DIAGRAMA', 3703, 3008]
['P&ID_ESTACIONES', 3833, 3008]
['DE', 4063, 3008]
['BOMBEO', 4110, 3008]
['1', 4226, 3008]
['DE', 4255, 3008]
['4', 4301, 3008]
['REVISI\xc3\x93N', 1241, 3006]
['Y', 1319, 3006]
['APROBACI\xc3\x93N', 1339, 3006]
['CLIENTE', 1449, 3006]
['F.G.V', 2091, 3006]
['A.S.M.', 2150, 3006]
['REVIEWED:', 3157, 3006]
['E.', 3255, 3007]
['AMESTICA', 3278, 3010]
['ENGINEERING', 3043, 3034]
['MANAGER:F.', 3163, 3035]
['GARCIA.', 3280, 3033]
['M.Q.G.', 1966, 3007]
['E.A.S.', 2028, 3007]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0104', 161, 3007]
['DIAGRAMA', 325, 3006]
['P&ID', 411, 3006]
['ESTACIONES', 460, 3006]
['DE', 565, 3006]
['BOMBEO', 596, 3006]
['4', 671, 3006]
['DE', 693, 3006]
['4', 723, 3006]
['C', 1076, 3005]
['20-06-17', 1138, 3006]
['20.06.17', 3517, 3007]
['C.Q.F.', 1965, 3034]
['M.Q.G.', 2022, 3035]
['I.D.V.A.S.M.', 2085, 3035]
['REVISION', 1241, 3033]
['Y', 1319, 3032]
['APROBACI\xc3\x93N', 1339, 3034]
['CLIENTE', 1449, 3033]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0103', 161, 3034]
['DIAGRAMA', 325, 3033]
['P&ID', 411, 3033]
['ESTACIONES', 460, 3033]
['DE', 565, 3033]
['BOMBEO', 596, 3033]
['3', 671, 3033]
['DE', 693, 3033]
['4', 723, 3033]
['02-12-16', 1138, 3033]
['20.06.17', 3517, 3033]
['REV', 4338, 3050]
['DWG.', 3846, 3048]
['NUMBER', 3895, 3049]
['SCALE:', 3620, 3056]
['C.Q.F.', 1965, 3061]
['M.Q.G.', 2022, 3062]
['I.D.V.A.S.M', 2084, 3062]
['PROJECT', 3080, 3060]
['MANAGER:', 3160, 3060]
['A.', 3256, 3060]
['SEGURA', 3277, 3063]
['EMITIDO', 1241, 3060]
['PARA', 1311, 3060]
['COORDINACION', 1361, 3060]
['INTERNA', 1487, 3060]
['21-11-16', 1138, 3060]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0102', 161, 3061]
['DIAGRAMA', 325, 3060]
['P&ID', 411, 3060]
['ESTACIONES', 460, 3060]
['DE', 565, 3060]
['BOMBEO', 596, 3060]
['2', 671, 3060]
['DE', 693, 3060]
['4', 723, 3060]
['A', 1075, 3060]
['20.06.17', 3517, 3062]
['QB1-5232-J-DW-0101', 3893, 3091]
['C', 4379, 3090]
['S/ESC', 3611, 3097]
['THIS', 3038, 3091]
['DRAWING', 3084, 3091]
['IS', 3163, 3091]
['COPYRIGHT', 3188, 3091]
['TECK', 3283, 3091]
['AND', 3333, 3091]
['IS', 3376, 3091]
['STRICTLY', 3401, 3091]
['CONFIDENTIAL', 3481, 3091]
['DRAWING', 162, 3097]
['NO', 255, 3099]
['NOTES', 2600, 3095]
['REV', 2022, 3098]
['N\xc2\xb0', 1089, 3097]
['DATE', 1152, 3097]
['DESCRIPTION', 1404, 3097]
['TITLE', 499, 3099]
['DR.', 1968, 3095]
['E.M', 2093, 3097]
['\xd0\xa0.\xd0\x9c.', 2157, 3096]
['Vi\\Mineria', 106, 3140]
['\\PY\\4768', 194, 3140]
['Impulsi\xc3\xb3n', 291, 3140]
['Cortina', 381, 3137]
['Hidr\xc3\xa1ulica', 460, 3137]
['Numero', 557, 3137]
['Uno', 632, 3137]
['Quebrada', 674, 3137]
['Blanca\\06', 770, 3137]
['Traspaso\\EMISION', 870, 3140]
['P&IDS\\4768-0110-11-PID-0101_C.dlwg', 1044, 3140]
['20-', 1363, 3137]
['jun-2017', 1394, 3140]
['1202', 1503, 3137]
['RELEASE', 1555, 3137]
['19.1s', 1640, 3137]
['(LMS', 1690, 3137]
['Tech)', 1739, 3137]
['MQUEZADA', 1800, 3140]
['PRINT', 1917, 3137]
['GENERA5D', 1977, 3142]
['20-jun-2017', 2084, 3141]
['1202', 2224, 3142]
['6', 2475, 3144]
['7', 2907, 3144]
['10', 4196, 3145]
['109', 91, 2897]
['\xd1\x85', 91, 2934]
['L\xd0\xb5', 91, 2954]
['-\xd1\x83', 91, 2988]
['REFERENCES', 139, 3039]
['(-3', 265, 1960]
['1', 356, 1967]
['1/2"-0110-WM-101-SS-1', 356, 1940]
['ULLUUNULI', 322, 2254]
['R.C.12"x2"', 341, 1096]
['1/2"-CH-101', 389, 2027]
['1', 384, 1712]
['1/2"-GL-101', 389, 1690]
['R.C.1"x2"', 689, 1095]
['1/2"-0110-WM-102-SS-1', 703, 1935]
['1/2"-CH-102', 738, 2028]
['1', 734, 1712]
['1/2"-GL-102', 738, 1690]
['1', 1049, 1957]
['1/2"-0110-WM-103-SS-1', 1052, 1935]
['R.C.12"X2"', 1040, 1096]
['SNOISIA', 1031, 2927]
["'-CH-103", 1084, 1991]
['1', 1083, 1711]
['1/2"-GL-103', 1087, 1691]
['R.C.1\xc2\xbd"x2"', 1512, 1096]
['1', 1524, 1957]
['1/2"-0110-WM-111-SS-1', 1527, 1935]
['1/2"-CH-111', 1563, 2026]
['1', 1558, 1712]
['1/2"-GL-111', 1563, 1690]
['R.C.12"x2"', 1863, 1096]
['1', 1872, 1956]
['1/2"-0110-WM-112-SS-1', 1876, 1942]
['1/2"-CH-112', 1913, 2028]
['1', 1906, 1711]
['1/2"-GL-112', 1911, 1690]
['R.C.12"X2"', 2212, 1095]
['1', 2228, 1966]
['1/2"-0110-WM-113-SS-1', 2228, 1942]
['1/2"-CH-113', 2262, 2028]
['1', 2257, 1712]
['1/2"-GL-113', 2261, 1690]
['-', 2289, 1791]
['o_o-', 2289, 1806]
['R.C.12"x2"', 2686, 1096]
['1', 2697, 1956]
['1/2"-0110-WM-121-SS-1', 2700, 1940]
["'-CH-121", 2731, 1991]
['1', 2731, 1712]
['1/2"-GL-121', 2736, 1689]
['R.C.12"x2"', 3038, 1096]
['1', 3051, 1965]
['1/2"-0110-WM-122-SS-1', 3052, 1942]
['1/2"-CH-122', 3084, 2027]
['1', 3081, 1711]
['1/2"-GL-122', 3084, 1689]
['R.C.12"x2"', 3388, 1097]
['1', 3403, 1967]
['1/2"-0110-WM-123-SS-1', 3403, 1940]
['"-CH-123', 3431, 1994]
['1', 3430, 1711]
['1/2"-GL-123', 3435, 1689]
]
```

El primer valor correspondería al texto encontrado, el segundo valor la coordenada X y el segundo valor la coordenada Y.

Para ésto se me ha ocurrido la idea de usar la función de OpenCV que detecta circulos y obtener la coordenadas de los circulos.

La lista que obtengo es algo como esto:

```py
[
[4170, 1558, 31]
[4170, 1374, 31]
[1600, 2010, 31]
[4170, 1498, 31]
[426, 2010, 31]
[634, 1992, 31]
[984, 1992, 31]
[1808, 1992, 31]
[2158, 1992, 31]
[2982, 1992, 31]
[270, 2318, 31]
[1444, 2318, 31]
[3320, 2318, 31]
[612, 2318, 31]
[774, 2010, 31]
[970, 2318, 31]
[1456, 1992, 31]
[1788, 2318, 31]
[1948, 2010, 31]
[2144, 2318, 31]
[2624, 2318, 31]
[2630, 1992, 31]
[2968, 2318, 31]
[2770, 2010, 31]
[3468, 2010, 31]
[4170, 1436, 31]
[282, 1992, 31]
[2294, 2010, 31]
[3330, 1992, 31]
[3118, 2010, 31]
[1120, 2010, 31]
[984, 1870, 31]
[2982, 1870, 31]
[2774, 1688, 31]
[634, 1870, 31]
[1124, 1688, 31]
[1808, 1870, 31]
[2298, 1688, 31]
[4170, 1170, 31]
[4170, 1230, 31]
[2356, 1750, 31]
[776, 1688, 31]
[1950, 1688, 31]
[3122, 1688, 31]
[3468, 1750, 31]
[284, 1870, 31]
[1458, 1870, 31]
[2632, 1870, 31]
[3530, 1752, 31]
[4170, 1112, 31]
[1660, 1750, 31]
[2008, 1750, 31]
[2294, 1750, 31]
[3330, 1866, 31]
[836, 1752, 31]
[1184, 1752, 31]
[3182, 1752, 31]
[424, 1754, 31]
[486, 1750, 31]
[1598, 1754, 31]
[2832, 1752, 31]
[3472, 1688, 31]
[424, 1688, 31]
[1120, 1750, 31]
[1598, 1688, 31]
[2772, 1750, 31]
[774, 1754, 31]
[3120, 1754, 31]
[1948, 1750, 31]
[2158, 1868, 31]
[4168, 986, 31]
[4168, 1294, 31]
[3776, 2556, 31]
]
```

El primer valor correspondería a la posición X, el segundo valor a la posición Y y el tercer valor al tamaño del radio del circulo.

La imagen que estoy analizando es algo como esto:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul9Ef.png

El tema que no se como hacer es hacer que al momento que vea que un item de la lista de texto coincide con una circunferencia (list generada por OpenCV) lo junte todo un solo item de la list de texto obtenido con OCR.

Imagino que es algo como con un for recorrer ambas listas e ir comparando las coordenadas pero sinceramente tengo poca idea de como hacerlo. Si me pueden echar una mano lo agradecería.

Nuevamente, muchas gracias!.

Comment: Hola, el problema es que la lista del OCR es de varios elementos, pero los quieres organizar de 3 en 3, y la otra lista es una lista de listas con 3 elementos cada una, correcto?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que, cuando el texto esté dentro de un circulo, se junte en un solo item de la list. Gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 2):

Cada círculo puede imaginarse inscrito en un cuadrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves por la figura, sabiendo el centro `(x,y)` y el radio del círculo, `r`, podemos obtener las coordenadas de las cuatro esquinas del cuadrado en el que se inscribe (sólo he rotulado dos en la figura).

Ya que en cada cuadrado de estos sólo hay un círculo, y en cada uno de ellos sólo una pareja de palabras ("LAH", o "0513" por ejemplo), podemos simplificar el problema y trabajar con esos cuadrados a la hora de determinar si la palabra está o no dentro del círculo. Basta mirar si *a la vez* la coordenada x de la palabra está entre `x-r` y `x+r`, y la coordenada y de la palabra está entre `y-r` e `y+r`. Si ambas cosas se cumplen, la palabra está dentro del cuadrado, y por tanto dentro del círculo.

Así que podemos escribir una función que nos dé si una coordenada `x_p, y_p` está o no dentro de la región de centro `x_centro, y_centro`, y radio `r`:

```py
def esta_dentro(x_p, y_p, x_centro, y_centro, r):
    return x_centro-r <= x_p <= x_centro+r and y_centro-r <= y_p <= y_centro+r
```

Usando esta función podemos tratar de agrupar las palabras dentro de los círculos que las contienen, con algo como:

```py
# Usando OpenCV obtenemos la lista de circulos
# y los tenemos en la lista circulos. Cada elemento de esta
# lista es una sublista tipo [x_centro, y_centro, radio]

# Usando OCR obtenemos la lista de palabras y las tenemos en 
# la lista palabras. Cada elemento de esta lista es una 
# sublista tipo  ["palabra", x_p, y_p]

# Lista para guardar los resultados
resultados = []

for region in circulos:
   x_centro = region[0]
   y_centro = region[1]
   radio = region[2]

   grupo = []
   for palabra in palabras:
      x_p = palabra[1]
      y_p = palabra[2]
      texto = palabra[0]
      if esta_dentro(x_p, y_p, x_centro, y_centro, radio):
         grupo.append(texto)
   if grupo:
      resultado.append(grupo)
```

Aunque no he podido testear este código por carecer de tus datos, si no me he equivocado al escribirlo al final deberías tener en resultado una lista cuyos elementos son parejas de palabras que están dentro del mismo círculo. Por ejemplo:

```
[["LAH", "0513"], ["LAL", "0513"], ["LALL", "0513"]]
```

### Nota

El código no es muy eficiente pues por cada círculo hallado ha de iterar por la lista de palabras para ver si están en ese círculo o no. Una vez se han encontrado un par de palabras que sí lo están, podría salirse del bucle interno y eliminarse ese par de la lista de palabras para evitar en la iteración siguiente tener que volver a pasar por ellas.

Si ves que tarda demasiado en ejecutarse, pon un comentario y trataré de mejorar el rendimiento. Pero *la optimización prematura es la raíz de todo mal* :-)

Comment: Loco eres un crack, esto ya va teniendo forma, la verdad es que esa funcion de esta_dentro me estaba comiendo la cabeza.

Una sola cosa, cuando ejecuto me tira el siguiente error y no entiendo de que va: 
```python

  File "<ipython-input-142-f240ab0f6395>", line 2, in <module>
    x_centro = region[0][0]

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Me temía que pudiera pasar esto. En tu pregunta pones ejemplos de listas tales como `[['LALL'],[1122],[1820], ...]` o `[[[1808], [1992], [31]], [[2158], [1992], [31]],...]` y la verdad, me extrañó tanto corchete. Quizás tus listas en realidad eran `['LALL`, 1122, 1820, ...]` o  `[[1808, 1992, 31], [2158, 1992, 31], ...]` que tendría mucho más sentido. Pero como no sabía qué tenías en realidad, asumí que eran tal y como pusiste en la pregunta. Por eso para acceder a cada dato tuve que poner un `[0]` al final, para tomar el (unico) elemento de esa lista interna.

Comment: Si las listas eran en realidad de la segunda forma, tienes que eliminar todos los `[0]` al final de las expresiones. Confírmame que este era el problema y edito la respuesta para que ya quede bien (aunque deberías entonces editar la pregunta para reflejar cómo son verdaderamente tus listas y así la respuesta concuerde con la pregunta).

Comment: Si, es un error que me di cuenta y he corregido los formatos de lista, lo haré tambien en el post principal para que lo mires, realmente aún soy muy nuevo en Python y cometo esos errores de novato, gracias por tu paciencia.

De momento he logrado juntar pero los resultados no son del todo exactos: https://imgur.com/a/GY74Ka3. Adjuntaré en el post principal el output de la lista del OCR también para que puedas verla.

Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!.

Comment: Si quisiera remover los items que han quedado por separado de la lista del OCR, ¿Cómo debería hacerlo?. Gracias por toda tu ayuda

Comment: Si te refieres a quedarte solo con las sublistas que tienen dos elementos puedes filtrarlas al terminar así: `filtrado = [e for e in resultado if len(e) ==2]`

Comment: No no, me refiero a remover de la lista de palabra  remover los items que junto en la otra lista, esto para que no estén duplicados, ¿me hago entender?. Gracias!